# trying to export a complex xml from excel 2013

Tags: xml, excel, export

I have exported records from an old financial system I have to MS Excel 2013. I need to take the data from MS Excel and need to change it to XML to upload to a different application.

The record is for a contract I have, which is basically a project with a bunch of employees who worked on the project.

I've had a lot of difficulty in getting a proper Excel export to XML. I do have an XSD and XML template.

What is the best solution for me to go from Excel to XML? Do I need to use VBA? Do I need a different program?

I am not a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the Excel data in an Excel-provided XML format by saving the workbook as `XML Speadsheet 2003 (*.xml)` file.

Then you can write and apply a [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) script to transform the data from one schema to another.

But it may be easier to use the Excel VBA and maybe even to export the data in different format acceptable by the "different application".

It may be also useful to do some data cleaning and rearranging to make the multi-stage transformation process simpler.

Definitely **hire a programmer**